Diagram chasing to show that $R[G\times H]$ is isomorphic to $R[G]\otimes R[H]$?
Let $R$ be just a commutative ring, and by $R[G]$ we denote the group ring, which is an R-module, but also an algebra with the ‘natural’ multiplication from the group.
While we can show explicitly that the group algebra $R[G\times H]$ is isomorphic to the tensor of the two group algebras. I suspect there must be some easy way to just use the universal properties of the tensor product, the free algebra, and the group product. Is there such a proof?
It is always nice to just draw some arrows to show that two constructions are isomorphic.

Yes, this can be done. You need to think about $\otimes$ as the "commutative coproduct": if $A, B$ are two $R$-algebras then $A \otimes_R B$ is the universal $R$-algebra equipped with morphisms from $A$ and from $B$ whose images commute. Then show that $G \times H$ is the "commutative coproduct" in groups, and imitate the proof that left adjoints preserve colimits.

Let's talk about monoid algebras, this is more general and a bit more convenient. I assume you are not necessarily looking for a proof using diagram chasing (which is not possible here), but rather for a proof using methods from category theory. Naturally, this will not be the shortest proof, but it explains more what is actually happening here.
The proof will heavily rely on the theory of monoidal categories. It is not sufficient to consider the barebone categories. In particular, notice that we have monoidal categories $(\mathbf{Mon},\times,1)$ and $(\mathbf{Alg}_R,\otimes_R,R)$, the first one being cartesian. One proof has already been explained by Qiaochu in the comments, but here is a different one.
The monoid algebra $R[-] : \mathbf{Mon} \to \mathbf{Alg}_R$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U_{+} : \mathbf{Alg}_R \to \mathbf{Mon}$. (The subscript indicates that we forget the additive structure, including the $R$-action, and we will have other forgetful functors below so this is why $U$ will not be enough.)
Notice that $U_+$ is lax monoidal: We have a natural morphism
$$\mu: U_+(A) \times U_+(B) \to U_+(A \otimes B), \quad (a,b) \mapsto a \otimes b,$$
suitably generalized to finitely many factors, which for $0$ factors then also includes the unit map. The multiplication on the tensor product of $R$-algebras is made exactly so that $\mu$ is a monoid homomorphism.
Now we may use the general result about monoidal adjunctions that the left adjoint $F_+ = R[-]$ of a lax monoidal functor becomes an oplax monoidal functor. Namely, we get the morphism of $R$-algebras
$$\begin{align*}
\check{\mu} : F_+(M \times N) & \xrightarrow{F_+(\eta \times \eta)} F_+(U_+(F_+(M)) \times U_+(F_+(N))) \\
& \xrightarrow{F_+(\mu)} F_+(U_+(F_+(M) \otimes F_+(N)))\\
& \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} F_+(M) \otimes F_+(N).
\end{align*}$$
Here we have used unit $\eta$ and counit $\varepsilon$ of the adjunction.
We want to prove that, actually, $\check{\mu}$ is an isomorphism, i.e. that $F_+$ is strong monoidal. For this, notice that we have a commutative square of forgetful functors
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\mathbf{Alg}_R @>{U_+}>> \mathbf{Mon} \\
@V{V_{\times}}VV @VV{U_{\times}} V \\
\mathbf{Mod}_R @>>{V_+}> \mathbf{Set}
\end{CD}$$
Therefore we also have a commutative-up-to-isomorphism square of left adjoints
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\mathbf{Alg}_R @<{F_+}<< \mathbf{Mon} \\
@A{G_{\times}}AA @AA{F_{\times}}A \\
\mathbf{Mod}_R @<<{G_+}< \mathbf{Set}
\end{CD}$$
Specifically:

$F_+$ is the monoid algebra
$G_+$ is the free module
$F_{\times}$ is the free monoid
$G_{\times}$ is the tensor algebra

We will not need $F_{\times}$ and $G_{\times}$. For formal reasons, there is always a morphism of functors
$$\vartheta : G_+ U_{\times} \longrightarrow V_{\times} F_+,$$
which in our case is an isomorphism. This is just a very abstract way of saying that the underlying module of the monoid algebra is the free module on the underlying set of the monoid; something which is baked into the concrete consruction of the monoid algebra. Notice that $\vartheta$ is not always an isomorphism for a given square of functors. It is called the Beck-Chevalley condition.
Since $V_+$ is conservative, it suffices to check that $V_{\times} \check{\mu}$ is an isomorphism. By the very construction of the tensor product of algebras, $V_{\times}$ is a strong monoidal functor, where of course we endow $\mathbf{Mod}_R$ with the usual tensor product $\otimes_R$. Also, $U_{\times}$ is strong monoidal by construction. Because of the Beck-Chevalley condition, we can therefore identify $V_+ \check{\mu}$ with a morphism
$$G_+(U_{\times}(M) \times U_{\times}(N)) \to G_+(U_{\times}(M)) \otimes G_+(U_{\times}(N)),$$
which is part of the oplax monoidal structure of $G_+$, which in turn is induced by the lax monoidal structure of its right adjoint $V_+$ (which is defined exactly as for $U_+$). Therefore, it suffices to prove that for all sets $X,Y$ the map
$$G_+(X \times Y) \to G_+(X) \otimes G_+(Y)$$
is an isomorphism (i.e. that $G_+$ is strong monoidal), which is a basic statement about free $R$-modules. All the work we have done so far was just to get rid of the multiplication.
To prove that the map is an isomorphism, notice that both sides are cocontinuous functors in $X$ and $Y$, and recall that every set is a coproduct of copies of $1$, the terminal set. Hence, it suffices to prove that the map is an isomorphism for $X=Y=1$, i.e. that $R \to R \otimes R$ is an isomorphism, which is of course true.

So here is the part that we can abstract from this proof. Assume that $(\mathcal{C}_i,\otimes)$ are monoidal categories and that we have a commutative square of lax monoidal functors
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}_1 @>{U_+}>> \mathcal{C}_2 \\
@V{V_{\times}}VV @VV{U_{\times}} V \\
\mathcal{C}_3 @>>{V_+}> \mathcal{C}_4
\end{CD}$$
which satisfies the Beck-Chevalley condition, meaning we have left adjoints $F_+ \dashv U_+$ and $G_+ \dashv V_+$ with $G_+ U_{\times} \xrightarrow{\sim} V_{\times} F_+$. Assume that $U_{\times}$, $V_{\times}$ and $G_+$ (which is oplax) are strong monoidal and that $V_{\times}$ is conservative. Then $F_+$ is strong monoidal.
